# Issue while running test script using shell."Shell script execution failed code 134"

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, npm, intern

I am trying to run test script using shell file, It is getting failed with 134 error code.
And getting this:

> Shell script execution failed code 134

Comment: Please include what you have tried thus far, source code to be precise.

Comment: Hello Yushin, 

Thank you but my issue is resolved. I just changed my prerequisite.